# Bokeh column layout of called function

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a bokeh script with some Sliders and Select options:

```
from bokeh.plotting import show
from bokeh.models import Select, Slider
from bokeh.layouts import row, column

def add_sliders():
    # defining sliders with start values:
    slider1 = Slider(title = 'Option1',start = 0, end = 10, step = 1, value = 6)
    slider2 = Slider(title = 'Option2',start = -1, end = 1, step = 1, value = 0)
    select1 = Select(title='Option3', value="In", options=["In","Out"])

   
    return slider1, slider2, select1

slider1, slider2, select1= add_sliders() 
l = column(slider1, slider2, select1 )
show(l)
```

Now, my question is: I don't want to state `slider1, slider2, select1= add_sliders()` but rather want to state `l = column(add_sliders())`, so a column layout of all output arguments of the called function add_sliders. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `column(children=add_sliders())` or `column(*add_sliders())`.

Comment: I saw the second option indeed worked. Another one is `column(list(add_sliders())`